# How to addStyleNames "Multiple css classes" into 1 element in UiBinder in GWT?

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder, gwtp

I have the need to apply many separated CSS classes into 1 element in UiBinder in GWT, but don't know how to do it.

In my TestView.ui.xml, i have

```
<g:Button  text="Log Out"  ui:field="logoutButton" addStyleNames="{style.gwt-Button}" addStyleNames="{style.paddedRight}" />
```

but it generated run-time error.

Then I tried

```
<g:Button  text="Log Out"  ui:field="logoutButton" addStyleNames="{style.gwt-Button style.paddedRight}" />
```

This time I got compile time error.

So, How to addStyleNames "Multiple css classes" into 1 element in UiBinder in GWT?

No info found on internet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I Think you have to specify each style name in `addStyleNames` property in a separate bracket pair.

Something like this:

```
<g:Button  text="Log Out"  ui:field="logoutButton" addStyleNames="{style.gwt-Button} {style.paddedRight}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs example [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World) uses single inverted commas.

```
<g:PushButton addStyleNames='{style.pretty} {style.hot}'>Push my hot button!</g:PushButton>
```

Double inverted commas don't work in my app (GWT 2.6)